# Not able to upload multiple files( with different uploader components ) in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, material-ui, firebase-storage

I have been trying to upload multiple images from the same react page with each of the files to be uploaded from different uploader elements.
I am trying to upload to firebase-storage.

I am using separate hooks to store the files in a function-based component until the upload function is called for each one of the files.

The error is when I try to select files from each of the uploaders, they only change one of the hook and others remain null. It acts as if only the setter function for the first hook in the JSX is called and even if I upload files from the other upload components, it updates the file whose setter function is called first in the JSX.
I have been using material-UI.
Assume, The setter functions are hooked up fine with each of the uploader function.

I have tried changing the setter function which is called first and I see that only that particular setter is called and others are overlooked.

Hooks for images:

```
const [Image1, setImage1] = useState(null);
const [Image2, setImage2] = useState(null);
const [Image3, setImage3] = useState(null);
```

I check for these when I save the info:

```
async function handleSave(){
 try{
     console.log(Image1);
     console.log(Image2);
     console.log(Image3);
   }
 }
 catch(err){
  console.error(err);
 }
```

}

In JSX :

```
<Grid item md={7}>
            <Typography variant="body1">Image1</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item md={5}>
            <input
              accept="image/*"
              className={classes.input}
              type="file"
              onChange = {e => {
                const file = e.target.files[0];
                uploadImage(file) //defined above 
                .then((file_obj) => {
                  setImage1(file_obj.fileURL);
                })
                .catch(err => console.error(err));
                }
              }
            />
            <label>
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                component="span"
                color="primary"
                className={classes.button}
              >
                Upload
                <CloudUploadIcon className={classes.rightIcon} />
              </Button>
            </label>
          </Grid>

<Grid item md={7}>
            <Typography variant="body1">Image2</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item md={5}>
            <input
              accept="image/*"
              className={classes.input}
              type="file"
              onChange = {e => {
                const file = e.target.files[0];
                uploadImage(file) //defined above 
                .then((file_obj) => {
                  setImage2(file_obj.fileURL);
                })
                .catch(err => console.error(err));
                }
              }
            />
            <label htmlFor="outlined-button-file">
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                component="span"
                color="primary"
                className={classes.button}
              >
                Upload
                <CloudUploadIcon className={classes.rightIcon} />
              </Button>
            </label>
          </Grid>

<Grid item md={7}>
            <Typography variant="body1">Image3</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item md={5}>
            <input
              accept="image/*"
              className={classes.input}
              type="file"
              onChange = {e => {
                const file = e.target.files[0];
                uploadImage(file) //defined above 
                .then((file_obj) => {
                  setImage3(file_obj.fileURL);
                })
                .catch(err => console.error(err));
                }
              }
            />
            <label htmlFor="outlined-button-file">
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                component="span"
                color="primary"
                className={classes.button}
              >
                Upload
                <CloudUploadIcon className={classes.rightIcon} />
              </Button>
            </label>
          </Grid>
//a button component here is used to call handleSave()
```

I expect each of the upload element to change their particular file hook but currently only one of the multiple(The one which is called first in the JSX) works

Comment: You've given all three of them the same ID ("outlined-button-file"). You should use unique IDs.

Comment: Thanks. This was just getting out of my sight for so long! Thank you very much.